# PHP unserialize error at offset, works on some servers, not others

Tags: php, serialization

I have code that works on a handful of servers, but not others which is coming up with serialised data. I call a page like this:

```
http://domain/index.php/sales/Drilldowns?params=a:12:{s:13:"selectionType";s:8:"facility";s:8:"dateType";s:5:"daily";s:10:"dateOption";s:9:"drilldown";s:6:"metric";s:13:"bookingAmount";s:9:"companyFK";s:2:"11";s:10:"facilityFK";s:0:"";s:7:"classFK";s:0:"";s:15:"customDateStart";s:4:"null";s:7:"newDate";s:10:"2010-11-01";s:10:"metricName";s:10:"Bookings%20$";s:16:"currentDateRange";s:10:"11/01/2010";s:23:"currentMetricNavigation";s:8:"DELDELTE";}&getExcel=0
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
protected function getRequestVariables(){
        if(isset($_REQUEST['params'])){
            var_dump($_REQUEST['params']);
            echo 'length:'.strlen($_REQUEST['params']);
            $vars = unserialize($_REQUEST['params']);
            var_dump($vars);
        } else {
            $vars = $_REQUEST;
            // unset saved drilldown options
            $this->ci->session->svar_set('postVars', null);
        }
```

This is a `var_dump` output:

```
string(447) "a:12:{s:13:\"selectionType\";s:8:\"facility\";s:8:\"dateType\";s:5:\"daily\";s:10:\"dateOption\";s:9:\"drilldown\";s:6:\"metric\";s:13:\"bookingAmount\";s:9:\"companyFK\";s:2:\"11\";s:10:\"facilityFK\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"classFK\";s:0:\"\";s:15:\"customDateStart\";s:4:\"null\";s:7:\"newDate\";s:10:\"2010-11-01\";s:10:\"metricName\";s:10:\"Bookings $\";s:16:\"currentDateRange\";s:10:\"11/01/2010\";s:23:\"currentMetricNavigation\";s:8:\"DELDELTE\";}"
```

When that gets processed I get the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 6 of 447 bytes
>   Filename: plugins/Drilldowns.php
>   Line Number: 93

I'm trying this on 5.2.13 - works on some Linux, some OS X, not others. Have checked php.ini, charset (I think) - I can't figure it out for the life of me. I've tried things as simple as

```
string(18) "a:1:{s:3:\"sam\";}" length:18
```

and it still errors. Any clue as to why?

Comment: Can you show the exact unserialize code you are using?

Comment: We need the code. It is probably something platform or version specific if it works just on some servers.

Comment: It works on 5.2 linux (Centos) but not 5.3 - fails on some Macs but not others

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's the backslashes in front of the quotes: `\"`

When you remove them, it works.

```
var_dump(unserialize('a:12:{s:13:"selectionType";s:8:"facility";s:8:"dateType";s:5:"daily";s:10:"dateOption";s:9:"drilldown";s:6:"metric";s:13:"bookingAmount";s:9:"companyFK";s:2:"11";s:10:"facilityFK";s:0:"";s:7:"classFK";s:0:"";s:15:"customDateStart";s:4:"null";s:7:"newDate";s:10:"2010-11-01";s:10:"metricName";s:10:"Bookings $";s:16:"currentDateRange";s:10:"11/01/2010";s:23:"currentMetricNavigation";s:8:"DELDELTE";}"'));
```

The servers this works on, probably have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on.

Comment: Magic quotes is off on all servers - the dump puts them there.. I'll post more code in a minute

Comment: @Sam  I get the same errors that you with the slashes, and they vanish when I remove them. Also, I'm pretty sure `var_dump` doesn't add slashes like that. Can you try a `stripslashes()` on the data?

Comment: you were right - I added stripslashes() and it worked. I've verified that magic_quotes is off - but I'll check in our framework that something isn't injecting those. Thanks a TON!

Comment: @Pekka: Is our code becomes vulnerable if we do this? Far little i understand slashes is added for security reasons right? Can you enlighten me?

Answer (score 22):

I had this problem and it took me a while to solve it. I just couldn't find any good solution but this is what I did  to solve my situation:

```
 base64_encode(serialize($User)); // make sure to encode the serialized object
 unserialize(base64_decode($User)); // decode it before unserializing
```

Comment: i don't know if i can reactive it this post , but i have the same issu and i'm using the base64_encode(serialize($data)) ...  how can i fix it ?

Comment: this was the only solution that really worked. regex replace sometimes won't work.