# Problem with serialize/unserialize and mcrypt when doing Signed Cookies

Tags: php, cookies, mcrypt

I'm working with a friend to get signed cookies on a website but I'm having a lot of problems when trying to encrypt it with mcrypt and MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256. I've the cookies working fine, so the problem is only when encrypting/decrypting the value of the cookie.

Here is the error is showed when trying to decrypt the cookie:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 93 bytes in /var/samba/www/xxx/src/data/include/yyy/Cookie.php on line 94
```

This exact line corresponds to:

```
$this->_cookie["value"] =  unserialize(mdecrypt_generic($tv, $cookie_value));
```

And here is how I manage to encrypt / decrypt.

First, send cookie.

```
    $tv = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, null, "ctr", null);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($tv), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($tv, "t3stp4ssw0rd", $iv);

    $this->_cookie["value"] =  base64_encode(mcrypt_generic($tv, serialize($this->_cookie["value"])));

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($tv);
    mcrypt_module_close($tv);

    setrawcookie($this->_cookie["name"],
                 $this->_cookie["value"],
                 $this->_cookie["expire"],
                 $this->_cookie["path"],
                 $this->_cookie["domain"],
                 $this->_cookie["secure"],
                 $this->_cookie["httponly"]);
```

PD: Yep, lovely test password ;-)

The value I see on firebug for the cookie is:

```
oKWdbVLX9T+mbOut4swo/aXr0g5O/3ApqfWZ1GZlrwwMSTa+M4n8Uey0UQs827HB7tilc/OzUPWQxoNvnAIkP5CFGkvgn+j+I36qN6dB0HmOUPlkNXJlz8Tfqxrjf8Gx
```

My get cookie, where I've to decrypt the value is:

```
    $this->_cookie["name"] = $cookie_name;
    $this->_cookie["value"] = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];

    $cookie_value = base64_decode($this->_cookie["value"]);

    $tv = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, null, "ctr", null);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($tv), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($tv, "t3stp4ssw0rd", $iv);

    $this->_cookie["value"] =  unserialize(mdecrypt_generic($tv, $cookie_value));

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($tv);
    mcrypt_module_close($tv);

    return $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
```

The problem is when I try to unserialize the value of the decrypted data. Anyone know where can be the problem?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**

```
    $cookie_value = base64_decode($this->_cookie["value"]);

    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, "", "cfb", "");
    $ks = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($td);
    $key = substr(sha1("t3stp4ssw0rd"), 0, $ks);

    $ivs = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);
    $iv = substr($cookie_value, 0, $ivs);

    $cookie_value = substr($cookie_value, $ivs);

    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);

    $cookie_value = mdecrypt_generic($td, $cookie_value);

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

    $this->_cookie["value"] =  unserialize($cookie_value);
```

Returns me error `Warning: mcrypt_generic_init(): Iv size incorrect; supplied length: 0, needed: 32`

Comment: What does `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` return? If `true`, do you pass cookie through `stripslashes()` before doing anything with it?

Comment: A `var_dump` returns me a int(0) so it returns `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That offset error normally means that the length of one of the values doesn't correspond to the specified length denoted by the serialized data. In my experience, this normally comes down to:

- as the previous poster said, backslashes being inserted to escape characters
- Encoding issues. This normally arises where some characters are computed as having one byte when serialized, but when unserializing they suddenly have 2 bytes. This can happen when you have, say, an ISO-8859-1 character set, but then some operation changes it to UTF-8.

If I were to take a guess, I'd say that the second point is probably where your problem lies. Your procedure in the first instance is serialize->encrypt->base64_encode, then you reverse the sequence, but I suspect that, somewhere along the line, your character encoding is getting messed up.

**Edited:**  Okay, I took a look at your code, and there's a problem with your encryption/decryption. Your decryption is not returning the decrypted value back. A while ago I came across this function (wish I could remember where so I can attribute it correctly) which is what I use for Mcrypt. It works for both encode and decode. Try it, and see if it sorts out your problem (the only thing it doesn't do is your base64_encode). I think your problem was that you were missing some required steps.

```
function encDec( $data, $key, $encrypt=true, $cypher='rijndael-128') {

    if (function_exists('mcrypt_module_open')) {

        # Serialize, if encrypting
        if ( $encrypt ) { $data = serialize($data); } 

        # Open cipher module
        if ( ! $td = mcrypt_module_open($cypher, '', 'cfb', '') )
            return false;

        $ks = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($td);     # Required key size
        $key = substr(sha1($key), 0, $ks);      # Harden / adjust length

        $ivs = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);     # IV size

        $iv = $encrypt ?
            mcrypt_create_iv($ivs, MCRYPT_RAND) :   # Create IV, if encrypting
            substr($data, 0, $ivs);                 # Extract IV, if decrypting

        # Extract data, if decrypting
        if ( ! $encrypt ) $data = substr($data, $ivs);

        if ( mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv) !== 0 ) # Initialize buffers
            return false;

        $data = $encrypt ?
            mcrypt_generic($td, $data) :    # Perform encryption
            mdecrypt_generic($td, $data);   # Perform decryption

        if ( $encrypt ) $data = $iv . $data;    # Prepend IV, if encrypting

        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);             # Clear buffers
        mcrypt_module_close($td);               # Close cipher module

        # Unserialize, if decrypting
        if ( ! $encrypt ) $data = unserialize($data);

    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: @Craig Sefton: thank you. look at the comments of the other answer, when unserializing the value characters like: `�?"V�\�Ns=q� }T��2`... this probably is what you're talking about? And if I refresh the page where the `var_dump` of the value to unserialize the value changes on every refresh.

Comment: @udexter: This is exactly what I'm referring to. If you don't have the correct encoding between your different operations, things are going to get very messed up when serialize/unserialize try to do their work. Btw, the value to unserialize will always change because of Mcrypt MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 (the encrypted value is never the same). You can show this by just refreshing a page where you encrypt a value and output it to the screen.

Comment: @udexter: Actually, I think you've got a different problem. I just ran your code without using serialize/unserialize, and the decrypt is not returning a decrypted value as far as I can see. I'll try look at it a bit more closely, but there's definitely a problem with that portion of the code.

Comment: @Craig: thank you! Anything you need let me know, but i think that there is no more needed that the send/get cookie. thank you!

Comment: @udexter: Just posted a function you may find useful. Enjoy.

Comment: @Craig: Thank you for your function. Btw, I'm getting some problems on decrypting. Check, I've updated the question with the decrypt I've mount on my get cookie and the error I'm getting. Thank u in advancd! (I accept right now the answer, because I think it's totally correct :P)

Comment: just for the record, I've facing some problems on trying to work with serialize and Amazon SWF. In the end, I used this combination to generate a full "clean" string:
`$encoded = base64_encode(addslashes(gzcompress(serialize($object),9)));`


`$decoded= unserialize(gzuncompress(stripslashes(base64_decode($encoded))));`

(from http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base64-encode.php#87925)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the quotes `"` in the cookie information are not escaped using back slashes. If they quotes are escaped, remove them before encrypting. See this thread -> [PHP unserialize error at offset, works on some servers, not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149030/php-unserialize-error-at-offset)

Comment: This is the var_dump of `serialize($this->_cookie["value"]);`: `string(96) "s:88:"YTozOntzOjM6InVpZCI7czoxOiIxIjtzOjY6ImxvZ2dlZCI7YjoxO3M6NToibGV2ZWwiO3M6NToiYWRtaW4iO30=";"`. Seems that " are not escaped, no?

Comment: And the most strange... this is the `var_dump()` BEFORE the unserialize: `string(96) "�?"V�\�Ns=q� }T�`�2��i��,�F$R���l����6Z� �v\ ���ͥ)�� 9~�p�c$�(����J��x�܁c�It^�K��"   ` and if I refresh, the value to unserialize changes.