# PHPMyAdmin encounters error 101::connection reset

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

It used to run well, but after I changed 'magic_quote_runtime' to be Off it encounters this problem.

I must change magic_quote_runtime to be off because i have the unserialize problem.(See [PHP unserialize error at offset, works on some servers, not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149030/php-unserialize-error-at-offset))

If phpmyadmin cannot run with magic_quote_runtime off how can i solve this two problem together?

Comment: I changed the magic_quotes_runtime back to be On but phpmyadmin still does't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try a couple of things..

- Restart apache
- clear browser's cache
- and if everything else fails..reinstall xampp (in case you have got phpmyadmin through xampp installation)

let us know if any of these helped or you have got any other solution that worked for you..